# Notepad++ - Turn big query from SQL Server into one line

Tags: notepad++, string-formatting

I've a big query from SQL Server in notepad++ (1012 lines) and I want to pass this query to only one line. For example, I've this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
WHERE Field_A = 1
```

And I want to pass to this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE Field_A = 1
```

I'm trying with the following codeS:

1. Open the Replace dialog ( Ctrl + H )
2. Check the Wrap around option
3. Choose the Regular expression search mode
4. Fill in the regex `(\h*\R)+` in the Find what: zone
5. Fill in the regex `\x20` in the Replace with: zone
6. Click on the Replace All button

But it's creating me some more new lines with a big space between the code.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried with CTRL+A and then CTRL+J? CTRL+J already adds a space, so you don't need to worry about breaking the SQL query.

Comment: @Andrea: This doesn't remove extra spaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to remove the spaces just after the linebreak, use this regex `(?:\h*\R\h*)+`

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\h*\R\h*)+`
- Replace with: `A SINGLE SPACE`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         : start non capture group
    \h*     : 0 or more horizontal spaces
    \R      : any kind of linebreak (ie. \r, \n, \r\n)
    \h*     : 0 or more horizontal spaces
)+          : end group, repeated 1 or more times
```

**Replacement:**

```
A single space
```

**Given example like:**

```
SELECT *

            FROM tableA



WHERE Field_A = 1
```

**Result for given example:**

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE Field_A = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just replace `\r\n`, the line ending, with a single space.  Note that I make the `\r` optional, in case you might be on Linux, where the line ending is just `\n`.

**Find:**

```
\r?\n
```

**Replace:**

```
[single space]
```

This would ensure at least a single space between the end of the previous line and start of the current line.  Extra whitespace should not cause a SQL query to be parsed incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Open the Replace dialog ( Ctrl + H )
2. Check the Wrap around option
3. Choose the Extended search mode
4. Fill in the regex \r\n in the Find what: zone
5. Put one white space in the Replace with: zone
6. Click on the Replace All button
```

Depending your newline convention, step 4. could be :

```
4bis. Fill in the regex \n in the Find what: zone
```

You can display newlines with :
`View -> Show symbols -> Show end of lines`.
If `CRLF` is displayed, doing step 4 will answere your question. If you see `LF`, you will need to do step 4bis.

As suggested by Tim Biegeleisen, you can also use the regular expression search mode (step 3) and fill in the regex `\r?\n`. This which does both at once.